# Creating a cache in Ruby methods

Tags: javascript, ruby, memoization

In **JavaScript**, it is fairly simple to memoize a function like Fibonacci:

```
// In JavaScript

var fibonacci = (function () {
  var cache = {}; // cache for future calculations

  return function (num) {
    if (num < 0)    throw new Error('Negative numbers not allowed');
    if (num === 0)  return 0;
    if (num === 1)  return 1;

    cache[num] = cache[num] || fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
    return cache[num];
  };
})();

console.log( fibonacci(5) ); // results in 5
console.dir( fibonacci ); // you can inspect the closure scope and see that the cache object saves the values for future use
```

I'm trying to understand how to do something similar in **Ruby** and unfortunately, the only thing I can come up with is creating a class and storing the cache as a class variable:

```
# In Ruby
class Placeholder
  @@cache = {}

  def fibonacci(num)
    raise 'Negative numbers not allowed' if num < 0
    return 0 if num == 0
    return 1 if num == 1

    @@cache[num] ||= fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2)
  end
end

example = Placeholder.new
puts example.fibonacci(5) # results in 5
```

What I don't like about this is the fact that I'm creating a class structure when I don't really intend to create instances of `Placeholder`. Instead, I'm only doing this because I want to save the state in a Ruby class variable. Ideally, if I were able to create a `module` and have a `module` variable, then that would at least solve my "problem" of instantiation with the `class` based solution. **What are your best suggestions for doing this in Ruby?**

**Update based on @meagar's comment:**

@meagar, are you suggesting something like this?

```
class Placeholder
  attr_reader :cache

  def initialize
    @cache = {}
  end

  def fibonacci(num)
    raise 'Negative numbers not allowed' if num  < 0
    return 0 if num == 0
    return 1 if num == 1

    @cache[num] ||= fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2)
  end
end

FibonacciCalculator = Placeholder.new
puts FibonacciCalculator.fibonacci(5) # results in 5
```

I already like this better than my initial Ruby solution, although having the Placeholder class still rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: You're essentially asking for C's `static` when in a function, right?

Comment: This might be a valid use for a global variable.

Comment: @Linuxios No, it's really not

Comment: Sorry @Linuxios I'm not very familiar with C so I'm not sure if  `static` addresses my question

Comment: @meagar: How isn't it? Values that persist between invocations of a function. That's what static means in a function in C, and that's what the OP is trying to do in Ruby.

Comment: @Linuxios A global variable is not the solution to this problem

Comment: @meagar: I disagree. This is **immutable** global data that is valid anywhere in a program.

Comment: No: http://pastebin.com/UYGTGQiu; Use real names, not `Placeholder`; use arrays, not objects; use `||=` to memoize when possible; use `<do something> if <condition>`, *never* `if <condition> then do something; end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't need instances, then you can use a `Module` with a singleton method:

```
module Fibonacci
  @cache = {}

  def self.series(num)
    if @cache[num] then return @cache[num]; end
    if num  < 0 then raise 'Negative numbers not allowed'; end
    if num == 0 then return 0; end
    if num == 1 then return 1; end

    @cache[num] = series(num - 1) + series(num - 2)
  end
end

puts Fibonacci.series(5) # results in 5
```

Note that for the cache, an instance variable on the `Fibonacci` module works just as well as a class variable (and for some extended uses, it could be better). It works because the module Fibonacci is an instance of `Module` - it is just the same as any other instance variable in that respect.

Comment: . . .  not too happy with the method name `.series`, but cannot think of anything better

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was hoping to be able to do - although I didn't realize that you can create instance variables in a module. Conceptually though, what does `instance variable` mean here since you're not creating instances of the module?

Comment: The module is an instance of the `Module` class. It's turtles all the way down in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Max - this is a slight aside but what happens to the `@cache` instance variable when you `include` the `Fibonacci` module into a class? Will the instances of the class be able to access `@cache`?

Comment: @wmock: No they will each have their own `@cache` variables. So if you are looking to do something more generic and sophisticated, you would probably consider having a dedicated caching/memoisation module/class, rather than this ad-hoc cache for a single method.

Comment: I would rename `series` to `call`, which is the standard name in Ruby for indicating that something is a "function". Plus, it allows you to call it as `Fibonacci.(5)`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I've not seen that before. Perhaps `:[]` would be nice too - allowing `Fibonacci[ 5 ]` - although I think both conventions would be OK, I also think making the code nicer is not answering the OP's question, and further differences from their original code could distract from the message.

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation of your ECMAScript version would be this:

```
fibonacci = -> {
  cache = {} # cache for future calculations

  -> num {
    raise ArgumentError, 'Negative numbers not allowed' if (num < 0)
    return 0 if num.zero?
    return 1 if num == 1

    cache[num] ||= fibonacci.(num - 1) + fibonacci.(num - 2)
  }
}.()

fibonacci.(5)
# => 5
fibonacci.binding.local_variable_get(:cache)
# => {2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>5}
```

By the way, there are a couple of simplifications we could do: instead of returning `0` if `num` is `0` and returning `1` if `num` is `1`, we could just return `num` if `num` is either `0` or `1` (or `num <= 1`). And in fact, we can get rid of that whole condition altogether by simply pre-initializing the `cache` with the values for `0` and `1`. Also, the cache can just be an `Array`, since the indices are just a contiguous range of `Integer`s:

```
fibonacci = -> {
  cache = [0, 1] # cache for future calculations

  -> num {
    raise ArgumentError, 'Negative numbers not allowed' if (num < 0)
    cache[num] ||= fibonacci.(num - 1) + fibonacci.(num - 2)
  }
}.()
```

Interestingly, if we write that in modern ECMAScript, then the relationship becomes obvious:

```js
const fibonacci = (() => {
    const cache = [0, 1, 1]; // cache for future calculations

    return num => {
        if (num < 0) throw new Error('Negative numbers not allowed');
        return cache[num] = cache[num] || fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
    };
})();

console.log(fibonacci(5));
```

Which in old-school ECMAScript would be this:

```js
var fibonacci = function () {
    var cache = [0, 1, 1]; // cache for future calculations

    return function (num) {
        if (num < 0) throw new Error('Negative numbers not allowed');
        return cache[num] = cache[num] || fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
    };
}();

console.log(fibonacci(5));
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the cool stuff with the latest version of JavaScript! @Jörg W Mittag

Answer (score 2):

> ... a class structure when I don't really intend to create instances of Placeholder

Well, there's your problem.

Ruby is an object-oriented language. You cannot have functions that do not belong to objects. *Every* method is invoked on an object.

You should simply create an instance of `Placeholder` (and give it an appropriate name like `FibonacciCalculator`) and make your cache a simple instance variable on that object.

Comment: Thanks for the input @meagar, I've updated my question with an example. Can you confirm if this is what you mean?

Comment: "You cannot have functions that do not belong to objects." – Of course you can: `-> x {x}` is the identity function and doesn't belong to any object, in fact, it is an object itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can also store the cache using a closure, which is similar to how javascript would do it.

```
def memoize func
  cache = {}
  proc do |*args|
    next cache[args] if cache[args]
    cache[args] = func[*args]
  end
end

def slow_double x
  sleep 2
  x * 2
end

memoized_double = memoize(method :slow_double)

memoized_double[4] # takes 2 seconds
memoized_double[4] # returns instantly
```